# There is no position in attributes BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

There is an object position in the mesh, but it is not duplicated into the geometry, is there any way to update the buffer geometry so that a position rejection appears in it?

I tried updating the position matrices but it didn't lead to anything

Comment: What? Uodating the mesh position will translate everything in that geometry. Not permanently, but on the fly during rendering. If you really want to start modifying the vertices to move position you need to get the buffer attributes and modify the whole array that gets fed into the WebGL context, but you shouldn't have to do that at all yourself...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is to do it like this

```js
const positions = new Float32Array( 100 * 3, 2);
mesh.geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
```